# Get Column Names from not well formed XML

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have an XML which is not well formed as I am getting this error when I am trying to read XML:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
ET.parse(r'my.xml')
```

I get the below error

> ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2034, column 317

So, I used `BeautifulSoup` to read the xml by below code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open(r'my.xml') as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'xml')
```

If I print `soup` it looks like this:

```
        <Placemark> 
<name>India </name> 
    <description>Country</description> 
    <styleUrl>#icon-962-B29189</styleUrl> 
    </Placemark>
        <Placemark> 
<name>USA</name>   
    <styleUrl>#icon-962-B29189</styleUrl> 
    </Placemark>            
    <Placemark>   
    <description>City</description> 
    <styleUrl>#icon-962-B29189</styleUrl> 
    </Placemark>
```

I have a total of more than 100 `Placemark` tags and the information in them. I want to capture `name` and `description` of each tag and make a `df` with respective columns.

My code for same is:

```
name_tag=[x.text.strip() for x in soup.findAll('name')]
description_tag =[x.text.strip() for x in soup.findAll('description')]
```

The problem is for some of the `Placemark` tags I don't have `name` or `description` tag at all. And hence I am not able to know which name has what description. So, there is a mismatch between name and description because of absence of tags.

**Expected Output Dataframe**:

```
Name      Description
India     Country
USA
           City
```

Is their any way I can achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are searching for `name` and `description` tags separately, you are losing track of which name belongs to which description.

Instead, you should parse each `placemark` tag on its own, and handle the case of missing `name` and `description` tags for each placemark tag.

```
data = []

for placemark in soup.findAll('placemark'):
    try:
        name = placemark.find('name').text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        name = None
    try:
        description = placemark.find('description').text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        description = None

    data.append((name, description))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Description'])
print(df)
#       Name    Description
#  0   India        Country
#  1     USA           None
#  2    None           City
```